# How do I get started writing a .NET-wrapper around C++ Omniorb-stubs?

Tags: .net, wrapper, managed-c++, corba

My job is to access a CORBA-server-application from .NET 3.5. After evaluating projects like IIOP.Net (undefined state) and products like VisiBroker (expensive) I'd like to do it "by myself" and write a .NET-Wrapper around C++-Stubs generated my Omniidl (the Omniorb IDL to C++ generator). This means writing some kind of layer of managed code (CLI) around the unmanaged C++ code.

I honestly don't know how to do it the best way. Right now I plan to create a managed class for every unmanaged class. Each managed class itself has a member to an instance of the unmanaged class, which is not garbage-collected. Is this the right way to do it or am I on the wrong path?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience this is one way to solve this problem - for every unmanaged class write a wrapper .NET class. You should look into using code generation so that you wouldn't need to write a lot of code.

Another option is to create .NET wrappers around common functionality - you could reduce some of the work by using a facade - if you have several classes that you need for a single operation or a group of operations you can create a single .NET class that manages all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I also think "wrapping everything" would be too much effort spent, writing some kind of facade and therefore wrapping only the needed methods and structs sounds more reasonable.

Code-generation sounds interesing, too: Would you happen to know any recommendable code-generators who would do the job? :)

Comment: You can use Code smith (http://www.codesmithtools.com/) for your code generation needs